# Django: how to use a variable key filter with __range

Tags: python, django, filter, range

```
date_one = form.cleaned_data.get('date_one')
date_two = form.cleaned_data.get('date_two')
date_type = form.cleaned_data.get('date_type')

search = MyClass.objects.filter(date_type__range(date_one, date_two))
```

My model has two different date columns. (`created` and `expires`). The user can make a query filtering between two dates, but he can choose if he wants to filter by creation or expiration.

I could make two query lines using `if`, but I really want to know how to do it in the way I'm asking.

How can I do this? Since the key before `__range` is a variable. I tried with `(**{ filter: search_string })` but it seems not to be compatible with `__range`.

Comment: You use `get()` so the result could also be `None` and you'll need to check that anyway. You should just use an if condition. It would be simpler to read the code.

Comment: You're saying you tried putting it into a dict and then passing that to filter? I was able to do that with __range, and it seems like the easiest solution.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks for your answer. Actually it won't be simpler since I've put a short example. I'm making many queries using others ifs, and it will turn a lot of if between others if in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
filter_dict = {"{}__range".format(date_type): [date_one, date_two]}
search = MyClass.objects.filter(**filter_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing you attempted is almost correct!

Lookups are not functions (so it's not `foo__range(start, end)`), but they are keyword arguments: `foo__range=(start, end)`

So you would have:

```
date_one = form.cleaned_data.get('date_one')
date_two = form.cleaned_data.get('date_two')
date_type = form.cleaned_data.get('date_type')

query_kwargs = {
   "{}__range".format(date_type): (date_one, date_two)
}
search = MyClass.objects.filter(**query_kwargs)
```

Comment: how is that different that @JPG's answer?

Comment: I didn't realise he submitted it just before me. However I also didn't just paste the "answer", I explained what was wrong.